# Request.QueryString in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, request.querystring

My code is work well but i want to send "Item" and "Mode" in encrypted form.any built in method in asp?if not plz suggest alternative solution.

```
string url = "QueryStringRecipient.aspx?";
url += "Item=" + lstItems.SelectedItem.Text + "&";
url += "Mode=" + chkDetails.Checked.ToString();
Response.Redirect(url);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encrypted or encoded?

To encode strings there is [`HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx)

```
public string UrlEncode(
    string s
)
```

**Parameters**

```
s
    Type: System.String
    The text to URL-encode.
```

**Return Value**

```
Type: System.String
The URL-encoded text.
```

---

To decode [`HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adwtk1fy.aspx)

```
public static string UrlDecode(
    string str
)
```

**Parameters**

```
str
    Type: System.String
    The string to decode.
```

**Return Value**

```
Type: System.String
A decoded string.
```

Comment: how to decript and catch real value?

Answer (score 4):

Try look here:

[Encrypting Query Strings](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/urlquerystring-encryption.aspx)

[Encrypting Query Arguments](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/security/encrypting-query-arguments)

You can also use `Session` variables.

---

Related posts:

[How can you secure/encrypt your querystring in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2989703/735864)

[How can I encrypt a querystring in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/240713/735864)

[how to pass encrypted query string in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603092/how-to-pass-encrypted-query-string-in-asp-net)

[How can i encrypt query string parameters in ASP.NET website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236088/how-can-i-encrypt-query-string-parameters-in-asp-net-website)