# Encrypted Query String

Tags: asp.net, security, query-string

I have used MachineKey.Encode to encrypt a ID that is getting passed as a query string to a page but as expected this is making the URL huge.

Is there a option such as HTTP handlers that could customize the url but still load the required page?

Also I am yet to find out if MachineKey.Encode is using the MachineKey that I have defined in my web.config file to encrypt the data, can anybody confirm this for me with web information that backs this up.

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989703/how-can-you-secure-encrypt-your-querystring-in-asp-net

Comment: not clear what is your problem here - not clear what you ask - what you try to solve.

Comment: I was passing a encrypted value as a query string and was wondering if there was a method customizing the url to not show the query string.

Comment: Couldn't you just 'POST' the request instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Also I am yet to find out if MachineKey.Encode is using the MachineKey that I have defined in my  web.config file to encrypt the data, can anybody confirm this for me with web information that backs this up.

It does indeed use the configured keys. `MachineKey` calls `MachineKeySection.EncryptOrDecryptData` to perform the encryption, which uses encryption objects configured from the machine key section. If you want to see for yourself, the interesting calls are  `EncryptOrDecryptData`=>`EnsureConfig`=>`ConfigureEncryptionObject`=>`SetKeyOnSymAlgorithm`